# Using a loop to set up an array string values?

Tags: arrays, loops

I'm hoping for a simpler way to declare the values of an array, since there will be 100 items in array. Here is what I currently have.

```
`var clipArray: Array = new Array(this.Seat_1, this.Seat_2, this.Seat_3, 
this.Seat_4, this.Seat_5, this.Seat_6, this.Seat_7, this.Seat_8, 
this.Seat_9, this.Seat_10, this.Seat_11, this.Seat_12);`
```

I've tried a loop like this and get "#1009 Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference."

```
`var clipArray: Array; for (var j:uint = 0; j <= 12; j++) {     
clipArray[j].ID = "this.Seat_" + j; } `
```

I also tried using a loop that calls a function.

Comment: Please format the code and clarify your question. Also,.what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please add this to the main post, not as a comment. All the necessary information, like code, exceptions, output and a comprehensible description of the problem belong into the question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask